How do I stop my discord bot from crashing when it messages a user that has blocked it? discord.js
So I don't know if I need to provide code for this one so I won't.
Basically me and a friend were experimenting with my bot. At one point I blocked it and asked my friend to use a command that would make the bot message me. They did, and the bot crashed. I definitely think that people are going to block this bot; it can get annoying, so how do I prevent it from crashing when it tries to DM a user that has blocked it?

A simple try catch would most likely be enough for this.
try {
    await command.execute(interaction);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    if (interaction.replied || interaction.deferred) {
        await interaction.followUp({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    } else {
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
}

Check out discord.js documentation about this, they go trough how you can prevent things like this.
